# Integrate $\int \csc^6(2x)\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I know to use the identity $1+\cot^2(2x)$.

I'm not sure how to use $u$-substitution to substitute the $2x$ from the problem.
I would have to use a $u$-substitution and then another $w$-substitution. The two values that I must create to substitute confuse me. Can I get ideas on how to solve?

Comment: Hints: $\csc^6 = (\csc^2)^3 = (1 + \cot^2)^3$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** 
Recall that $\csc^2 \theta = 1 + \cot^2 \theta$.  Let us perform the substitution $\theta = 2x$.  Then,
$$\int \csc^6 2x ~dx = \frac{1}{2} \int \csc^6 \theta ~d\theta$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2} \int(1+\cot^2\theta)^2\csc^2\theta ~ d\theta$$
If $u = \cot \theta$, then $du = \cdots$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:-**

> $$(n-1)I_n=-\dfrac{\cos2 x}{2\sin^{n-1} 2x}+(n-2)I_{n-2}$$

Where $I_n=\displaystyle\int\dfrac{dx}{\sin^n {2x}}$